# How to disable ESC to exit fullscreen macOS High Sierra?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I've already tried mapping a different shortcut to the "Exit Full Screen" menu item in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts but hitting ESC still exits fullscreen mode in any application.

This is mildly infuriating since escape is used in some applications for other purposes.

Answer (score 14):

Download Karabiner, a keymap remapper tool for Mac. There's a 'template' for what you want: 
https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/#safari

It disables the escape key in Safari only - exactly what you need... Or remap the esc key globally for all apps.

Works like a charm.

Comment: This worked great for me (I did have to install karabiner first though). Thank you!

Comment: Does it break Esc from doing what it is supposed to do in Safari? e.g. closing dialog windows.

Comment: @WilliamEntriken Yes and No. In full-screen-mode the default action of 'esc' is to jump out of full screen mode. Not closing a dialog window.
This is also the case in Mojave.

Comment: Installed, works, thank you. Test case https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp // with this can keep full screen and ESC to close modal popup.

Comment: I am happy since this worked, thanks

Answer (score -1):

For the use case when Safari or Safari Technology Preview is in  full screen and you have a modal window open that you wish to close but not exit full screen mode, then you can also hit ⌘+ESC.

Answer (score -3):

If your application is meant to operate in full-screen mode only, you shouldn't use NSWindow's full screen feature; it's designed to let the user turn it on and off. Instead, you should enter full-screen mode directly using `NSView`'s `enterFullScreenMode(withOptions:)` method. This will give you a lot more control over the whole full-screen experience, and won't let the user automatically turn it off.

Comment: I'm not developing an application, I'm trying to disable this feature globally for all applications

Comment: @rahul Okay, I'd given you the benefit of the doubt that this was a programming question. Now that we know that it isn't, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic for the site. Have a nice day!